# Tell Ubuntu: Erase all partitions, use entire disk for LVM

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 19.04, lvm

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 19.04 server over an Ubuntu 19.04 Desktop install , and I selected "Use entire disk with LVM" option.

However, it's not using entire disk for / . It keeps setting it to 4GB when the SSD I'm installing to is 256GB ( 231GB available on the LVM ).

Shouldn't the automatic partitions scheme try to use 100% of the LV for the install?  I can manually force it to do that, I but I'd think that part would be automatic as well.

Comment: It looks from here like your 256GB SSD is a GPT disk which ordinarily means that the Ubuntu installer would create a small 500MB FAT EFI System partition for grub bootloader. For some reason it didn't create a 500MB FAT EFI System partition and now it thinks the whole SSD is FAT! FAT has a limit of 4GB. Exit from the Ubuntu installer and select the Try Ubuntu option. Try Ubuntu has GParted partition editor. In GParted you can create the two partitions you need: 1. a small 500MB FAT EFI System partition and 2. a big ext4 / partition for the Ubuntu operating system. Then try to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Try what she said.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else works, you can

- Remove 'every trace' of the previous partition table by wiping the first mibibyte (overwrite with zeros).

  [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) can wipe the first mibibyte in a safe way.
- Create a partition table (but without any partitions).

  Use **gparted** when booted from a separate live drive. Select

  - Device - Create Partition Table ...
- Now there is no cruft that is confusing the installer. Things will work.

---

- There are detailed descriptions of what partitions there should be in different boot modes and partition tables at [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace), but I think the installer can do it automatically.